# XMl and XSL % displays wrong

Tags: xml, xslt

I seem to have one small problem I have my xml and XSl files what appears correct but percentages are off.  This is how it is supposed to display by Rank, movie name number of votes and the percentage of votes.

This is kind of what it would like hopefully I explained it so others can understand.

```
Rank    Movie                     Votes     %
1       Dr.  Strangelove (1964)   95        58.64%
2       Tootsie (1982)            82        50.62%
```

xml code

```
        <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="comedy.xsl" ?> 

    <poll>
    <ballot id="b1">
       <movie>A FISH CALLED WANDA (1988)</movie>
       <movie>ADAM'S RIB (1949)</movie>
       <movie>ANNIE HALL (1977)</movie>
       <movie>BEING THERE (1979)</movie>
       <movie>BORN YESTERDAY (1950)</movie>
       <movie>CITY LIGHTS (1931)</movie>
       <movie>DR. STRANGELOVE (1964)</movie>
       <movie>GOOD MORNING, VIETNAM (1987)</movie>
       <movie>HIS GIRL FRIDAY (1940)</movie>
       <movie>M*A*S*H (1970)</movie>
       <movie>MOONSTRUCK (1987)</movie>
       <movie>NATIONAL LAMPOON'S ANIMAL HOUSE (1978)</movie>
       <movie>SILVER STREAK (1976)</movie>
       <movie>SOME LIKE IT HOT (1959)</movie>
       <movie>THE GENERAL (1927)</movie>
       <movie>THE GRADUATE (1967)</movie>
       <movie>THE ODD COUPLE (1968)</movie>
       <movie>THE SEVEN YEAR ITCH (1955)</movie>
       <movie>TO BE OR NOT TO BE (1942)</movie>
       <movie>WHAT'S UP, DOC? (1972)</movie>
    </ballot>
    <ballot id="b2">
       <movie>A DAY AT THE RACES (1937)</movie>
       <movie>A SHOT IN THE DARK (1964)</movie>
       <movie>AMERICAN GRAFFITI (1973)</movie>
       <movie>BALL OF FIRE (1941)</movie>
       <movie>BLAZING SADDLES (1974)</movie>
       <movie>CADDYSHACK (1980)</movie>
       <movie>DR. STRANGELOVE (1964)</movie>
       <movie>GHOSTBUSTERS (1984)</movie>
       <movie>HIS GIRL FRIDAY (1940)</movie>
       <movie>IT'S A MAD MAD MAD MAD WORLD (1963)</movie>
       <movie>MODERN TIMES (1936)</movie>
       <movie>NATIONAL LAMPOON'S ANIMAL HOUSE (1978)</movie>
       <movie>SHAMPOO (1975)</movie>
       <movie>SOME LIKE IT HOT (1959)</movie>
       <movie>THE AWFUL TRUTH (1937)</movie>
       <movie>THE GRADUATE (1967)</movie>
       <movie>THE ODD COUPLE (1968)</movie>
       <movie>THE PRODUCERS (1968)</movie>
       <movie>THIS IS SPINAL TAP (1984)</movie>
       <movie>TOPPER (1937)</movie>
    </ballot>
    <ballot id="b3">
       <movie>A NIGHT AT THE OPERA (1935)</movie>
       <movie>AIRPLANE! (1980)</movie>
       <movie>ARSENIC AND OLD LACE (1944)</movie>
       <movie>BEVERLY HILLS COP (1984)</movie>
       <movie>BRINGING UP BABY (1938)</movie>
       <movie>DINER (1982)</movie>
       <movie>DUCK SOUP (1933)</movie>
       <movie>HAROLD AND MAUDE (1972)</movie>
       <movie>IT HAPPENED ONE NIGHT (1934)</movie>
       <movie>M*A*S*H (1970)</movie>
       <movie>MR. DEEDS GOES TO TOWN (1936)</movie>
       <movie>RAISING ARIZONA (1987)</movie>
       <movie>SINGIN' IN THE RAIN (1952)</movie>
       <movie>THE APARTMENT (1960)</movie>
       <movie>THE GOLD RUSH (1925)</movie>
       <movie>THE JERK (1979)</movie>
       <movie>THE PHILADELPHIA STORY (1940)</movie>
       <movie>THE THIN MAN (1934)</movie>
       <movie>TOOTSIE (1982)</movie>
       <movie>YOUNG FRANKENSTEIN (1974)</movie>
    </ballot>
    <ballot id="b4">
       <movie>A FISH CALLED WANDA (1988)</movie>
       <movie>ADAM'S RIB (1949)</movie>
       <movie>ANNIE HALL (1977)</movie>
       <movie>BEING THERE (1979)</movie>
       <movie>BORN YESTERDAY (1950)</movie>
       <movie>CITY LIGHTS (1931)</movie>
       <movie>DUCK SOUP (1933)</movie>
       <movie>GROUNDHOG DAY (1993)</movie>
       <movie>HORSE FEATHERS (1932)</movie>
       <movie>M*A*S*H (1970)</movie>
       <movie>MOONSTRUCK (1987)</movie>
       <movie>NINOTCHKA (1939)</movie>
       <movie>SINGIN' IN THE RAIN (1952)</movie>
       <movie>SULLIVAN'S TRAVELS (1941)</movie>
       <movie>THE GENERAL (1927)</movie>
       <movie>THE GRADUATE (1967)</movie>
       <movie>THE PHILADELPHIA STORY (1940)</movie>
       <movie>THE SEVEN YEAR ITCH (1955)</movie>
       <movie>TO BE OR NOT TO BE (1942)</movie>
       <movie>WHAT'S UP, DOC? (1972)</movie>
    </ballot>
    <ballot id="b5">
       <movie>A DAY AT THE RACES (1937)</movie>
       <movie>ABBOTT AND COSTELLO MEET FRANKENSTEIN (1948)</movie>
       <movie>AMERICAN GRAFFITI (1973)</movie>
       <movie>BANANAS (1971)</movie>
       <movie>BLAZING SADDLES (1974)</movie>
       <movie>CAT BALLOU (1965)</movie>
       <movie>DR. STRANGELOVE (1964)</movie>
       <movie>GHOSTBUSTERS (1984)</movie>
       <movie>HIS GIRL FRIDAY (1940)</movie>
       <movie>IT'S A MAD MAD MAD MAD WORLD (1963)</movie>
       <movie>MODERN TIMES (1936)</movie>
       <movie>NATIONAL LAMPOON'S ANIMAL HOUSE (1978)</movie>
       <movie>SHE DONE HIM WRONG (1933)</movie>
       <movie>SOME LIKE IT HOT (1959)</movie>
       <movie>THE COURT JESTER (1956)</movie>
       <movie>THE GRADUATE (1967)</movie>
       <movie>THE ODD COUPLE (1968)</movie>
       <movie>THE PRODUCERS (1968)</movie>
       <movie>THIS IS SPINAL TAP (1984)</movie>
       <movie>VICTOR/VICTORIA (1982)</movie>
    </ballot>
    <ballot id="b6">
       <movie>A FISH CALLED WANDA (1988)</movie>
       <movie>ADAM'S RIB (1949)</movie>
       <movie>ANNIE HALL (1977)</movie>
       <movie>BEING THERE (1979)</movie>
       <movie>BORN YESTERDAY (1950)</movie>
       <movie>CITY LIGHTS (1931)</movie>
       <movie>DR. STRANGELOVE (1964)</movie>
       <movie>GOOD MORNING, VIETNAM (1987)</movie>
       <movie>HIS GIRL FRIDAY (1940)</movie>
       <movie>M*A*S*H (1970)</movie>
       <movie>MONKEY BUSINESS (1931)</movie>
       <movie>NATIONAL LAMPOON'S ANIMAL HOUSE (1978)</movie>
       <movie>SILVER STREAK (1976)</movie>
       <movie>SOME LIKE IT HOT (1959)</movie>
       <movie>THE GENERAL (1927)</movie>
       <movie>THE GRADUATE (1967)</movie>
       <movie>THE ODD COUPLE (1968)</movie>
       <movie>THE SEVEN YEAR ITCH (1955)</movie>
       <movie>TO BE OR NOT TO BE (1942)</movie>
       <movie>WHAT'S UP, DOC? (1972)</movie>
    </ballot>
</poll>
```

XSL code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
 <xsl:key name="kMovieByName" match="movie" 
  use="."/> 

 <xsl:variable name="vTotalNumber" 
      select="count(/*/*/movie)"/> 

 <xsl:template match="/"> 
  <html> 
    <head> 
     <title>Top American Comedies</title> 
     <link href="comedy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <h2>The Top American Comedy Films</h2> 
        <p>Number of Ballots:162</p> 
        <table> 
            <tr> 
                <th>Rank</th> 
                <th>Movie</th> 
                <th>Votes</th> 
                <th>%</th> 
                <xsl:apply-templates select= 
                 "/*/*/movie 
                        [generate-id() 
                        = 
                         generate-id(key('kMovieByName',.) 
                                   [1]) 
                        ] 
                 "> 
                 <xsl:sort select="count(key('kMovieByName',.))" 
                           data-type="number" 
                           order="descending"/> 
                </xsl:apply-templates> 
            </tr> 
        </table> 
   </body> 
  </html> 
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: You should probably post some example XML and the XSL.

Comment: yeah sorry I was trying to finally got it posted.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:key name="kMovieByName" match="movie"
      use="."/>

     <xsl:variable name="vTotalNumber"
          select="count(/*/ballot)"/>

     <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <head>
         <title>Top American Comedies</title>
         <link href="comedy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <h2>The Top American Comedy Films</h2>
            <p>Number of Ballots: <xsl:value-of select="$vTotalNumber"/>
            </p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Rank</td>
                    <td>Movie</td>
                    <td>Votes</td>
                    <td>%</td>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select=
                     "/*/*/movie
                            [generate-id()
                            =
                             generate-id(key('kMovieByName',.)
                                       [1])
                            ]
                     ">
                     <xsl:sort select="count(key('kMovieByName',.))"
                               data-type="number"
                               order="descending"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </tr>
            </table>
       </body>
      </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="movie">
  <xsl:variable name="vVotes" select="key('kMovieByName', .)"/>
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/>. </td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="count($vVotes)"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select=
    "format-number(100* count($vVotes) div $vTotalNumber, '##.#')
    "/>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<poll>
    <ballot id="b1">
        <movie>A FISH CALLED WANDA (1988)</movie>
        <movie>ADAM'S RIB (1949)</movie>
        <movie>ANNIE HALL (1977)</movie>
        <movie>BEING THERE (1979)</movie>
        <movie>BORN YESTERDAY (1950)</movie>
        <movie>CITY LIGHTS (1931)</movie>
        <movie>DR. STRANGELOVE (1964)</movie>
        <movie>GOOD MORNING, VIETNAM (1987)</movie>
        <movie>HIS GIRL FRIDAY (1940)</movie>
        <movie>M*A*S*H (1970)</movie>
        <movie>MOONSTRUCK (1987)</movie>
        <movie>NATIONAL LAMPOON'S ANIMAL HOUSE (1978)</movie>
        <movie>SILVER STREAK (1976)</movie>
        <movie>SOME LIKE IT HOT (1959)</movie>
        <movie>THE GENERAL (1927)</movie>
        <movie>THE GRADUATE (1967)</movie>
        <movie>THE ODD COUPLE (1968)</movie>
        <movie>THE SEVEN YEAR ITCH (1955)</movie>
        <movie>TO BE OR NOT TO BE (1942)</movie>
        <movie>WHAT'S UP, DOC? (1972)</movie>
    </ballot>
    <ballot id="b2">
        <movie>A DAY AT THE RACES (1937)</movie>
        <movie>A SHOT IN THE DARK (1964)</movie>
        <movie>AMERICAN GRAFFITI (1973)</movie>
        <movie>BALL OF FIRE (1941)</movie>
        <movie>BLAZING SADDLES (1974)</movie>
        <movie>CADDYSHACK (1980)</movie>
        <movie>DR. STRANGELOVE (1964)</movie>
        <movie>GHOSTBUSTERS (1984)</movie>
        <movie>HIS GIRL FRIDAY (1940)</movie>
        <movie>IT'S A MAD MAD MAD MAD WORLD (1963)</movie>
        <movie>MODERN TIMES (1936)</movie>
        <movie>NATIONAL LAMPOON'S ANIMAL HOUSE (1978)</movie>
        <movie>SHAMPOO (1975)</movie>
        <movie>SOME LIKE IT HOT (1959)</movie>
        <movie>THE AWFUL TRUTH (1937)</movie>
        <movie>THE GRADUATE (1967)</movie>
        <movie>THE ODD COUPLE (1968)</movie>
        <movie>THE PRODUCERS (1968)</movie>
        <movie>THIS IS SPINAL TAP (1984)</movie>
        <movie>TOPPER (1937)</movie>
    </ballot>
    <ballot id="b3">
        <movie>A NIGHT AT THE OPERA (1935)</movie>
        <movie>AIRPLANE! (1980)</movie>
        <movie>ARSENIC AND OLD LACE (1944)</movie>
        <movie>BEVERLY HILLS COP (1984)</movie>
        <movie>BRINGING UP BABY (1938)</movie>
        <movie>DINER (1982)</movie>
        <movie>DUCK SOUP (1933)</movie>
        <movie>HAROLD AND MAUDE (1972)</movie>
        <movie>IT HAPPENED ONE NIGHT (1934)</movie>
        <movie>M*A*S*H (1970)</movie>
        <movie>MR. DEEDS GOES TO TOWN (1936)</movie>
        <movie>RAISING ARIZONA (1987)</movie>
        <movie>SINGIN' IN THE RAIN (1952)</movie>
        <movie>THE APARTMENT (1960)</movie>
        <movie>THE GOLD RUSH (1925)</movie>
        <movie>THE JERK (1979)</movie>
        <movie>THE PHILADELPHIA STORY (1940)</movie>
        <movie>THE THIN MAN (1934)</movie>
        <movie>TOOTSIE (1982)</movie>
        <movie>YOUNG FRANKENSTEIN (1974)</movie>
    </ballot>
    <ballot id="b4">
        <movie>A FISH CALLED WANDA (1988)</movie>
        <movie>ADAM'S RIB (1949)</movie>
        <movie>ANNIE HALL (1977)</movie>
        <movie>BEING THERE (1979)</movie>
        <movie>BORN YESTERDAY (1950)</movie>
        <movie>CITY LIGHTS (1931)</movie>
        <movie>DUCK SOUP (1933)</movie>
        <movie>GROUNDHOG DAY (1993)</movie>
        <movie>HORSE FEATHERS (1932)</movie>
        <movie>M*A*S*H (1970)</movie>
        <movie>MOONSTRUCK (1987)</movie>
        <movie>NINOTCHKA (1939)</movie>
        <movie>SINGIN' IN THE RAIN (1952)</movie>
        <movie>SULLIVAN'S TRAVELS (1941)</movie>
        <movie>THE GENERAL (1927)</movie>
        <movie>THE GRADUATE (1967)</movie>
        <movie>THE PHILADELPHIA STORY (1940)</movie>
        <movie>THE SEVEN YEAR ITCH (1955)</movie>
        <movie>TO BE OR NOT TO BE (1942)</movie>
        <movie>WHAT'S UP, DOC? (1972)</movie>
    </ballot>
    <ballot id="b5">
        <movie>A DAY AT THE RACES (1937)</movie>
        <movie>ABBOTT AND COSTELLO MEET FRANKENSTEIN (1948)</movie>
        <movie>AMERICAN GRAFFITI (1973)</movie>
        <movie>BANANAS (1971)</movie>
        <movie>BLAZING SADDLES (1974)</movie>
        <movie>CAT BALLOU (1965)</movie>
        <movie>DR. STRANGELOVE (1964)</movie>
        <movie>GHOSTBUSTERS (1984)</movie>
        <movie>HIS GIRL FRIDAY (1940)</movie>
        <movie>IT'S A MAD MAD MAD MAD WORLD (1963)</movie>
        <movie>MODERN TIMES (1936)</movie>
        <movie>NATIONAL LAMPOON'S ANIMAL HOUSE (1978)</movie>
        <movie>SHE DONE HIM WRONG (1933)</movie>
        <movie>SOME LIKE IT HOT (1959)</movie>
        <movie>THE COURT JESTER (1956)</movie>
        <movie>THE GRADUATE (1967)</movie>
        <movie>THE ODD COUPLE (1968)</movie>
        <movie>THE PRODUCERS (1968)</movie>
        <movie>THIS IS SPINAL TAP (1984)</movie>
        <movie>VICTOR/VICTORIA (1982)</movie>
    </ballot>
    <ballot id="b6">
        <movie>A FISH CALLED WANDA (1988)</movie>
        <movie>ADAM'S RIB (1949)</movie>
        <movie>ANNIE HALL (1977)</movie>
        <movie>BEING THERE (1979)</movie>
        <movie>BORN YESTERDAY (1950)</movie>
        <movie>CITY LIGHTS (1931)</movie>
        <movie>DR. STRANGELOVE (1964)</movie>
        <movie>GOOD MORNING, VIETNAM (1987)</movie>
        <movie>HIS GIRL FRIDAY (1940)</movie>
        <movie>M*A*S*H (1970)</movie>
        <movie>MONKEY BUSINESS (1931)</movie>
        <movie>NATIONAL LAMPOON'S ANIMAL HOUSE (1978)</movie>
        <movie>SILVER STREAK (1976)</movie>
        <movie>SOME LIKE IT HOT (1959)</movie>
        <movie>THE GENERAL (1927)</movie>
        <movie>THE GRADUATE (1967)</movie>
        <movie>THE ODD COUPLE (1968)</movie>
        <movie>THE SEVEN YEAR ITCH (1955)</movie>
        <movie>TO BE OR NOT TO BE (1942)</movie>
        <movie>WHAT'S UP, DOC? (1972)</movie>
    </ballot>
</poll>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

      <title>Top American Comedies</title>
      <link href="comedy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>The Top American Comedy Films</h2>
      <p>Number of Ballots: 6</p>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Rank</td>
            <td>Movie</td>
            <td>Votes</td>
            <td>%</td>
            <tr>
               <td>1. </td>
               <td>THE GRADUATE (1967)</td>
               <td>5</td>
               <td>83.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>2. </td>
               <td>DR. STRANGELOVE (1964)</td>
               <td>4</td>
               <td>66.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>3. </td>
               <td>HIS GIRL FRIDAY (1940)</td>
               <td>4</td>
               <td>66.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>4. </td>
               <td>M*A*S*H (1970)</td>
               <td>4</td>
               <td>66.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>5. </td>
               <td>NATIONAL LAMPOON'S ANIMAL HOUSE (1978)</td>
               <td>4</td>
               <td>66.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>6. </td>
               <td>SOME LIKE IT HOT (1959)</td>
               <td>4</td>
               <td>66.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>7. </td>
               <td>THE ODD COUPLE (1968)</td>
               <td>4</td>
               <td>66.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>8. </td>
               <td>A FISH CALLED WANDA (1988)</td>
               <td>3</td>
               <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>9. </td>
               <td>ADAM'S RIB (1949)</td>
               <td>3</td>
               <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>10. </td>
               <td>ANNIE HALL (1977)</td>
               <td>3</td>
               <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>11. </td>
               <td>BEING THERE (1979)</td>
               <td>3</td>
               <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>12. </td>
               <td>BORN YESTERDAY (1950)</td>
               <td>3</td>
               <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>13. </td>
               <td>CITY LIGHTS (1931)</td>
               <td>3</td>
               <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>14. </td>
               <td>THE GENERAL (1927)</td>
               <td>3</td>
               <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>15. </td>
               <td>THE SEVEN YEAR ITCH (1955)</td>
               <td>3</td>
               <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>16. </td>
               <td>TO BE OR NOT TO BE (1942)</td>
               <td>3</td>
               <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>17. </td>
               <td>WHAT'S UP, DOC? (1972)</td>
               <td>3</td>
               <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>18. </td>
               <td>GOOD MORNING, VIETNAM (1987)</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>33.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>19. </td>
               <td>MOONSTRUCK (1987)</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>33.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>20. </td>
               <td>SILVER STREAK (1976)</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>33.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>21. </td>
               <td>A DAY AT THE RACES (1937)</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>33.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>22. </td>
               <td>AMERICAN GRAFFITI (1973)</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>33.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>23. </td>
               <td>BLAZING SADDLES (1974)</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>33.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>24. </td>
               <td>GHOSTBUSTERS (1984)</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>33.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>25. </td>
               <td>IT'S A MAD MAD MAD MAD WORLD (1963)</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>33.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>26. </td>
               <td>MODERN TIMES (1936)</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>33.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>27. </td>
               <td>THE PRODUCERS (1968)</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>33.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>28. </td>
               <td>THIS IS SPINAL TAP (1984)</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>33.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>29. </td>
               <td>DUCK SOUP (1933)</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>33.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>30. </td>
               <td>SINGIN' IN THE RAIN (1952)</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>33.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>31. </td>
               <td>THE PHILADELPHIA STORY (1940)</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>33.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>32. </td>
               <td>A SHOT IN THE DARK (1964)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>33. </td>
               <td>BALL OF FIRE (1941)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>34. </td>
               <td>CADDYSHACK (1980)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>35. </td>
               <td>SHAMPOO (1975)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>36. </td>
               <td>THE AWFUL TRUTH (1937)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>37. </td>
               <td>TOPPER (1937)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>38. </td>
               <td>A NIGHT AT THE OPERA (1935)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>39. </td>
               <td>AIRPLANE! (1980)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>40. </td>
               <td>ARSENIC AND OLD LACE (1944)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>41. </td>
               <td>BEVERLY HILLS COP (1984)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>42. </td>
               <td>BRINGING UP BABY (1938)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>43. </td>
               <td>DINER (1982)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>44. </td>
               <td>HAROLD AND MAUDE (1972)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>45. </td>
               <td>IT HAPPENED ONE NIGHT (1934)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>46. </td>
               <td>MR. DEEDS GOES TO TOWN (1936)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>47. </td>
               <td>RAISING ARIZONA (1987)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>48. </td>
               <td>THE APARTMENT (1960)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>49. </td>
               <td>THE GOLD RUSH (1925)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>50. </td>
               <td>THE JERK (1979)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>51. </td>
               <td>THE THIN MAN (1934)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>52. </td>
               <td>TOOTSIE (1982)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>53. </td>
               <td>YOUNG FRANKENSTEIN (1974)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>54. </td>
               <td>GROUNDHOG DAY (1993)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>55. </td>
               <td>HORSE FEATHERS (1932)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>56. </td>
               <td>NINOTCHKA (1939)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>57. </td>
               <td>SULLIVAN'S TRAVELS (1941)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>58. </td>
               <td>ABBOTT AND COSTELLO MEET FRANKENSTEIN (1948)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>59. </td>
               <td>BANANAS (1971)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>60. </td>
               <td>CAT BALLOU (1965)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>61. </td>
               <td>SHE DONE HIM WRONG (1933)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>62. </td>
               <td>THE COURT JESTER (1956)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>63. </td>
               <td>VICTOR/VICTORIA (1982)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>64. </td>
               <td>MONKEY BUSINESS (1931)</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>16.7</td>
            </tr>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```